# How to create array from text file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file look like:

## data.txt:

'[[74, 180], [74, 215], [72, 210], [72, 210],.... [73, 195]]'

I'm bit stuck on how to iterate through the files in a directory and simultaneously place them into a 2D array. The code I have so far is:

```py
import numpy as np
f=open("data.txt","r",encoding="utf-8")
data=f.read()
array=np.array(data,dtype=np.int64)
print(array)

The output that I am seeking is array
[[ 74 180]
 [ 74 215]
 [ 72 210]
 ...
 [ 75 205]
 [ 75 190]
 [ 73 195]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('data.txt');
df.to_numpy();
```

this output should give you numpy array.
check pandas documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html

Answer (score 0):

The format you showed is JSON, if you didn't have quotes, if closing bracket wasn't missing, and if there is no ellipsis. Also, `numpy`, not `nupym`. Please make sure the information in the question is correct. If those assumptions are true, the solution is:

```
import numpy as np
import json

with open("data.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    array = np.array(json.load(f))
```